# What's a simple way to share gradle settings between gradle builds

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I've got an app which now includes a gradle build for a wearable app.

So both build.gradle files have something like

```
    versionCode 1230
    versionName "1.23.0"
```

Is there a simple properties file I can place the two values in and then reference them in both builds so I don't forget to update both and help ensure they both stay the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `gradle.properties` file in the project root will have its properties injected as what amount to global variables available to your `build.gradle` files.

So, for example, I might have a `gradle.properties` file in the project root that has:

```
PUBLISH_GROUP_ID=com.commonsware.cwac
PUBLISH_ARTIFACT_ID=anddown
PUBLISH_VERSION=0.2.1
LOCAL_REPO=file:///this/would/be/a/real/path/to/a/local/maven/repository
```

Then, in `modulename/build.gradle` (where `modulename` is `app` or `anddown` or whatever your module is), I can refer to those values:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        pom.groupId = PUBLISH_GROUP_ID
        pom.artifactId = PUBLISH_ARTIFACT_ID
        pom.version = PUBLISH_VERSION

        repository(url: LOCAL_REPO)
    }
}
```